# C++ Coding Guideline 102

Tags: c++, coding-style

If you were allowed to add another coding guideline to the 101 guidelines of the ["C++ coding standards" (Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu)](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), which would you add?

Answer (score 4):

Write for a year later.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for: "*avoid considering **goto**, **naming notation** and **indentation** as being the subjects of coding rules*"

Comment: This is very similar to "don't sweat the small stuff".

Answer (score 0):

Rule 102: Any change to expected functionality should result in a regression test that fails.

Comment: I agree. But it's not really a C++-rule.

Comment: Several of the existing 101 rules are not C++ specific.

Answer (score 0):

"*Use RAII judiciously"*

Comment: Could you elaborate? Has RAII hidden dangers that escaped our notice?

Comment: Less experienced coders have no idea of what's "judicious" and more experienced one may have professional differences of opinion, so this falls a bit short of a useful guideline. A good guideline would define what's judicious.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer constructors to init()/setup() functions.

Why manipulating an object that may be in an unusable state? Isn't it better to not have it at all ?