# Your least favorite C++ Coding guideline

Tags: c++, coding-style

As a counterpart to [C++ Coding Guideline 102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215470/c-coding-guideline-102), which of the [101 guidelines of Sutter & Alexandrescu](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) do you violate or ignore most often, and why?

Answer (score 5):

I'd say for me, it's probably 16. Avoid macros. I find there are a good number of things I can only do with macros (especially inlining __FILE__ and __LINE__ into expressions), and many cases where I need a compact expression which operates in the external function context (checking result codes and returning, for example). As a result, my code tends to be sprinkled liberally with assertions in the form of macros, for example, so I'd say this is one I ignore quite a bit.

That said, I would forgo most of my uses if the language allowed alternative similarly compact expressions of the same concepts, but since it does not, macros will be around for a long time.

I should add, it's not to say that I think the suggestion is bad, or it's bad to follow it when you have an alternative available. I just find that I end up using a lot of macros, usually because there's no alternative available.

Comment: Good point, though I usually avoid macros, there certainly are some reasonable uses for them.

Comment: The thing is, "avoid" isn't the same as "don't ever use".  Having no better alternative sounds like a good enough explanation to use them while abiding the guideline.

Answer (score 5):

I broke 19 (always initialize variables) on this site only yesterday. My code snippet was:

```
uint64_t i = getIEEEbitpatternByMeansRelevantToTheQuestion();
double d;
memcpy(&d, &i, 8);
```

Can't see any point in initializing d: there is no value which could possibly be meaningful, and the compiler will either ignore the value I do provide or else do something wasteful with it.

Initializing non-POD types, and POD types which are members of classes, is eminently sensible. Initializing something just to memcpy/memset over it, not so much.

In fact, one of the reasons for initializing non-PODs is to avoid a default construction that you just assign over the top of later. Initializing a POD that you're planning to scribble over is basically the same bad thing.

I don't have the book, though, so it could be that's what they mean and the "always" in the title is misleading.

Comment: But you did initialize d - you just used memcpy to initialize it!

Comment: You could do: double d = *((double *)&i); instead. No need to use memcpy at all.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I have naturally over time developed habits which match these guidlines almost perfectly. Following these types of coding standards leads to clean, easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 2):

No. 56 - Use vector by default.  I often use a deque instead.  Interestingly, Herb Sutter [appears to be conflicted on this himself](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I like a good c-style cast now and then, I'm afraid to admit. (I realize the problems with it - just can't help myself)

Answer (score 1):

*72. Prefer to use exceptions to report errors.*

Instead, I use *72-ALT. Don't throw exceptions.* :)

Ok, except for reporting caller's precondition violations in the *public API layer* of a published code library - and in that layer only.

Answer (score 0):

I ignore most of them, because they can be summarized as: use C++ as if it were a high-level object-oriented language. But if you want a high-level object-oriented language, there are much better candidates (C#, Java, Lisp, Python etc). C++ is essentially the mother of all structured macro assemblers, and I use it as such, and only in jobs where that is what is required.

Comment: Er, sounds like you're thinking of C, rather than C++.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking of C++ rather than Java-- ;)

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at [all the rules](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), it would be: *89. Write function objects correctly*. I never take the time to write them correctly. Sometimes I use variadic functions, but it is not exactly a choice I have.